# Validating junit test cases that access Neo4j DB using Spring Framework

Tags: java, junit, spring-boot

I am developing a spring boot application that accesses data to and fro from a Neo4j database. There are junit test cases to validate certain functionalities.

I am facing a strange scenario.

I have a Person class, whose objects are being stored in the database using a PersonRepository class which extends extends GraphRepository.

Inside the junit test case I am calling a method of a @Service class which does the following

```
 public void getAndUpdatePerson(String username){

    Person p1 = personRepository.findOneByUuid(username);
    Person p2 = personRepository.findOneByUuid(username);

    System.out.println("-------------");
    System.out.println(p1==p2); // true
    p1.setFullName("ASDF");
    System.out.println(p2.getFullName()); //ASDF
    p1.setFullName("QWER");
    System.out.println(p2.getFullName()); //QWER
    System.out.println("-------------");

 }
```

The outputs of the println(s) have been provided along with the statements.
From the outputs, it seems that both p1 and p2 refer to the same object although they have been retrieved from the database separately. Whwnever there is a change in object p1, the change also gets reflected in object p2.

Is this behaviour ok ? If so why ?